# Complex binding for list not working .net 6 in [FromForm]

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, .net-6.0

I am trying to pass complex list of data to .net core web api controller but values are not binding, below is the code that I am using.

```
public IActionResult Add([FromForm]List<SponsorViewModel> sponsorDetailsList,
                                                          IFormFile profilePic)
```

Can anyone please help? I already checked other stack overflow questions but it is not solving the issue.

Comment: Can you share you how to pass data to action?

Answer (score 0):

The form key/value pair looks like this

```
Key: sponsorDetailsList[0][Id]
Value: 1

Key: sponsorDetailsList[0][Name]
Value: John
```

cURL format for example

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://localhost:7149/api' \
--form 'sponsorDetailsList[0][Id]="1"' \
--form 'sponsorDetailsList[0][Name]="John"'
```

Tested in Postman. Works well with both List and File together.

**Update**

This is a bare minimum of working code

form

```
<form action="/api" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="number" name="sponsorDetailsList[0][Id]" />
    <input type="text" name="sponsorDetailsList[0][Name]" />
    <input type="file" name="profilePic" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

controller method

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Add([FromForm] List<SponsorViewModel> sponsorDetailsList, IFormFile profilePic)
{
    return Ok();
}
```

I think you can imagine a more complex scenario, even with JS and so on.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions but, how it will work on swagger.

Comment: Not sure how this work in swagger

Comment: @AkashGaikwad did you manage to get an answer for this?

Comment: No @TheGodfather, for time being I created two separate apis.

Comment: @AkashGaikwad ok thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found that sending multiple complex objects with files are not properly supported and you need to process both differently in .NetCore 6.

How are you sending data from client side ?

If using `AJAX`, you need to send a `FormData` and disable processing data and its content type.

```
let myObject = {...}; // your object
let array_of_files = [...]; // your files as an array

let formData = new FormData();

// set the object as the first element to be sent
formData.append("sponsorDetailsList", JSON.stringify(myObject));

// set the files as to send them after the object
$.each(array_of_files , function(i, file) {
    formData.append("profilePic", file);
});

$.ajax({
    type: "post",
    url: "?handler=Add",
    dataType: "json",
    data: formData,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    headers: { "RequestVerificationToken": $("input[name=\"__RequestVerificationToken\"]").val() },
    success: function(response) {
    },
    error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
    }
});
```

And in your controller (assuming you are using Razor pages, adapt it if not)

```
public IActionResult OnPostAdd([FromForm] List<IFormFile> profilePic) {
    // need to deserialize sponsorDetailsList separately
    try {
        List<SponsorViewModel> sponsorDetailsList = Enumerable.Empty<SponsorViewModel>().ToList();

        foreach (var data in HttpContext.Request.Form.Keys.Select((val, i) => new { key = val, intIndex = i })) {
            if (data.intIndex == 0) // first element sent is the object
                sponsorDetailsList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<SponsorViewModel>>(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(HttpContext.Request.Form[data.key]) ? HttpContext.Request.Form[data.key] : new Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives.StringValues());
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        // error occured while deserializing
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not necessary to separate it. It works well in .NET 6

Comment: I actually disagree. Tried every solution that sends both the data and the files together and the controller would not deserialize either of them. Please provide a solution if you have one that works without hassle.

Comment: Sure thing, you can check my updated answer

Comment: Used exactly that solution in a previous project with no success. C# could not deserialize my object as a valid class. I had to manually force it. Will check my old dusty app and see if it will accept it this time.

Comment: For now I am using swagger to test the APIs. later on these apis will be consumed by angular layer, but I am not sure why list is not binding if I pass it from swagger.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that Since files are attached in the body, during form  submit
is in multipart form data. So try using [FromBody] instead of [FromForm]

Comment: If I use from body then file is not passed. it will treat it as a JSON and not multi part form data.

Comment: A github sample project reference  would be a great help!

Comment: Do you have any reference link?

Comment: I meant your project's reference link so that I can try and undertand more!

Comment: I think this is an example of how it's generally better to ask for clarification before giving an answer based on an assumption and then finding out the answer doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

What it is a POST request, Data will come in the request body. try [FromBody]

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Add([FromBody]List<SponsorViewModel> sponsorDetailsList,                                                          IFormFile profilePic)
```

Comment: No I want to access file in the same api.